# Laravel- Check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') < Now()' at line 1

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting this error when executing my program with Laravel:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') < Now()' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `house` where `isoccupied` = 0 and (currentdatasync + INTERVAL '1 DAY') < Now())
```

my function in my controller is:

```
  public function view()
    {
        $failed = DB::table('house')
            ->where('isoccupied', 0)
            ->whereRaw("(currentdatasync + INTERVAL '1 DAY') < Now()")
            ->count('*');

        return view('admin.dashboard')->with('failed', $failed);
    }
```

I have tried to use

```
return view('admin.dashboard')->with(compact($failed));
```

however it still does not work.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Don't quote the duration `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not have to use `+ INTERVAL '1 DAY'`.

Try to use

```
public function view()
    {
        $failed = DB::table('house')
            ->where('isoccupied', 0)
            ->whereRaw("subdate(currentdatasync, 1) < Now()")
            ->count('*');

        return view('admin.dashboard')->with('failed', $failed);
    }
```

Or replace `subdate(currentdatasync, 1)` with `subdate(currentdatasync, -1)` depending on if you need yesterday or tomorrow (1 is yesterday, -1 is tomorrow)

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to use `INTERVAL` use it like this:

```
public function view()
    {
        $failed = DB::table('house')
            ->where('isoccupied', 0)
            ->whereRaw("(`currentdatasync` + INTERVAL 1 DAY) < NOW()")
            ->count('*');

        return view('admin.dashboard')->with('failed', $failed);
    }
```

Comment: I disagree. the `INTERVAL` syntax is SQL standard syntax which makes the query more portable.

Comment: I have provided fully working query, please provide your own solution except of comment others :) If you know how to use `INTERVAL` in this case, I like to learn something new.